# C++ Windows API - how to use a ListView's default WIndows Proc?

Tags: c++, windows, api, mfc

Okay, I have a ListView and I've just worked out how to manually set it's Callback procedure:

```
// Sets the list view procedure
listproc = (D_ListView *) LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, sizeof(D_ListView));
               listproc->oldproc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(g_hList, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG)&ListViewProc);
               SetWindowLongPtr(g_hList, GWL_USERDATA, (LONG)&listproc);
```

I used a code example I found - `D_ListView` is just a `struct` with a `WNDPROC` variable called `oldproc`.

Anyhow, I'm sending messages to my ListView to add items. But I don't want to handle the ADD messages manually, I want to pass them onto the ListView's default procedure, and only handle messages that I need to over-ride the functionality for.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK ListViewProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        // Just a test - we're getting this message so it worked
        case LVM_INSERTCOLUMN:
        {
            cout << "CREATED" << endl;

        }    
    }
    WNDPROC* wp;
    wp = (WNDPROC*)(::GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC));
    return ::CallWindowProc(*wp, hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);   
}
```

In the above, I don't want to deal withe LVM_INSERTCOLUMN: I just want to pass it on.

Any one able to help?

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

use `getWindowLongPtr (...GWL_USERDATA)` to get the pointer to your `D_ListView` instance and then forward any unwanted messages to `oldproc`

`::CallWindowProc(*listproc->oldproc, hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);`

Comment: But the callback function that's being called *is* the one I added with the D_ListView instance. I check that with my cout message.

Comment: @user1853098, you don't seem do understand what you are doing... You set wndproc using `SetWindowLongPtr` which returns the pointer to **default** ListView wndproc, you then save this pointer in your `listproc->oldproc` and store it in 'user data'. Now to call the default proc you need to retreive your struct from user data and use it.

Comment: Oh, I see now. My apologies - I have the old procedure function here so I can still use it (as it gets returned from the initial SetWindowLongPtr. Thanks so much!

Comment: Actually this still isn't passing messages I don't use to the original function (no columns are added and I know that code works).

D_ListView *listproc;
listproc = (D_ListView*)GetWindowLongPtr(g_hList, GWL_USERDATA);
and I use:
return ::CallWindowProc(*listproc->oldproc, hwnd,msg,wParam,lParam);

This is at the bottom of my function. No extra columns are added when I try to add them.

Comment: @user1853098, you store it in user data as a 'pointer to pointer' (why by the way?) but retrieve as a value. You have to be consistent.

Comment: I'm new to MFC so I'm using example code for now - the pointer to a pointer seemed to work (I thought it was some weird MFC datatype), so I'm can't devour a few programming books like I usually do.

And, no, this html window seems to have ditched the asterisks that denote pointers from my code.

D_ListView *listproc;
listproc = (D_ListView*)GetWindowLongPtr(g_hList, GWL_USERDATA);

Comment: Nope, won't display it. But there's an asterisk before both D_ListViews (they're D_ListView) pointers. I'd post it as an answer but I have to wait 8 hours on StacOverflow because I'm new.

Comment: @user1853098, in your call `SetWindowLongPtr(g_hList, GWL_USERDATA, (LONG)&listproc);` remove `&` before `listproc`